# Read .txt file with columns seperated by quotation marks with rows over several lines in R

Tags: r, read.table

I am having problems reading a .txt file to R. It should contain one id column and one text column in the end. The structure of the file is as follows:

```
"", "textOriginal"
"1," "some text"
"2," "some text"
"3," "some text"
```

and there are also a lot of entries in which the text is split over several lines, like that:

```
"4," "some
      more
      text"
```

However, I want to avoid that R makes three rows out of the fourth text, so basically I want everything inside the quotation marks to be in one row with the respective id. I tried read.table(mytext.txt), header = TRUE) but I don't get the desired result...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this hack, starting with a text file:

```
"", "textOriginal"
"1," "some text"
"2," "some text"
"3," "some text"
"4," "some
      more
      text"
```

The code:

```r
quux <- readLines("quux.txt")
quux2 <- stringr::str_extract_all(paste(paste0(quux, ifelse(cumsum(nchar(gsub('[^"]', '', quux))) %% 2 == 0, ",", "\n")), collapse = ""), '"[^"]*"')[[1]]
quux2
#  [1] "\"\""                             "\"textOriginal\""                 "\"1,\""                          
#  [4] "\"some text\""                    "\"2,\""                           "\"some text\""                   
#  [7] "\"3,\""                           "\"some text\""                    "\"4,\""                          
# [10] "\"some\n      more\n      text\""

data.frame(matrix(quux2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
#     X1                             X2
# 1   ""                 "textOriginal"
# 2 "1,"                    "some text"
# 3 "2,"                    "some text"
# 4 "3,"                    "some text"
# 5 "4," "some\n      more\n      text"
```

The overall goal is to:

1. read this in as text;
2. add commas to sentences that are quote-complete and add newlines (`\n`) to lines that are not;
3. concatenate all of that into one continuous vector;
4. extract all sequences of the literal `"`, zero or more non-`"`, then another `"`;
5. use a `matrix` formation to construct the `data.frame`. (Rename as desired.)

Walk-through:

- `cumsum(nchar(..))` counts the number of quotation marks on a line. We do it cumulative so that (for instance, the `more` line is counted as still being incomplete.
- `ifelse(..)` based on whether `cumsum` is odd (incomplete quotes) or even (quote-complete), append a newline or a comma;
- `paste0` (append) this to the original lines;
- `paste` (concatenate) all things into one string;
- then extract all lengths of string that have a double-quote, some (or none) non-quotes, then another double-quote.

You can clean it up if you want with:

```r
# quux3 <- ...above...
quux3[] <- lapply(quux3, gsub, pattern = '^"|\"$', replacement = '')
quux3
#   X1                           X2
# 1                    textOriginal
# 2 1,                    some text
# 3 2,                    some text
# 4 3,                    some text
# 5 4, some\n      more\n      text
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I detected a last little issue. Some of the textOriginal columns contain quotation marks themselves which is why in the end some texts end up in the ID column and mess up the formatting...: Do you know a way how to only split by the quotation mark around the entire text row?

Comment: (1) If your data looks differently than what I have in the `quux.txt` file generated from your question, then you should update your question to have a more representative example that includes what you just mentioned. (2) Frankly ... whatever/whomever is generating this format appears to be intentionally making it difficult to parse. If you have any say over the format you receive it in (whether or not it is your script/code making it), I strongly suggest you request something more deterministic and more-easily parsed (e.g., json).

Comment: The data is outputted by translation software, unfortunately, I cannot change the format. However, I now just removed the quotation marks inside the text before feeding it to the software. Thanks again! Your solution worked perfectly! :)

Answer (score 2):

To read this text file (saved as `test.txt`)

```
"", "textOriginal"
"1," "some text"
"2," "some text"
"3," "some text"
"4," "some
      more
      text"
```

We can use `read_delim` from `readr` package with `" "` set as delimiter

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(readr)

text_file <- readr::read_delim("test.txt", delim = " ") %>% 
  rename("id" = `,`, "textOriginal" = "textOriginal")
```

```r
text_file

# A tibble: 4 × 2
# id textOriginal                      
# <dbl> <chr>                             
# 1     1 "some text"                       
# 2     2 "some text"                       
# 3     3 "some text"                       
# 4     4 "some\r\n      more\r\n      text"
```

Then some string manipulation will get a nice output

```r
text_file %>% 
  mutate(
    textOriginal = str_remove_all(textOriginal, pattern = "[\\r\\n]") %>% 
      str_squish()
  )

# A tibble: 4 × 2
# id textOriginal  
# <dbl> <chr>         
# 1     1 some text     
# 2     2 some text     
# 3     3 some text     
# 4     4 some more text
```

Answer (score 0):

An attempt using `read.csv` and `strsplit`:

```
t <- read.csv(yourfile, header = TRUE)
strsplit(t[,1],"," )

[[1]]
[1] "1"          " some text"

[[2]]
[1] "2"          " some text"

[[3]]
[1] "3"          " some text"

[[4]]
[1] "4"                             " some\n      more\n      text"
```